# Python - save x values from a column to list when a number in another column is bigger than the number before 2

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

(Hi I'm new to this so I might not know the best way to formulate this question but here goes)

I'm using pandas btw!

I am looking for a construct to each time save x values (let's say x=3 so three values) from one column to a list when a number in another column is bigger than the number before. First number should not be considered. Important to note that there are also missing data in the number column (NaN).

```
Number         Value
23             4
23             5
NaN            8
24             6    # <--
24             23
24             26
24             11
25             2    # <--
25             1
25             3
25             5
Nan            9
26             4    # <--
26             6
NaN            9
26             12
```

Hopefully in the end the new list contains:

```
List = [6, 2, 4]
```

Thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and then compare if [`series.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) is greater then 0, then slice the number of elements you want in `x`(here 3):

```
x=3
df.loc[df['NumberColumn'].ffill().diff().gt(0),'Value'].tolist()[:x]
#[6, 2, 4]
```

Comment: this worked! Awesome! I changed in my question the column name from "NumberColumn" to "Number", but your method really works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
df.Value[df.Number.shift().ffill() < df.Number].tolist()[:3]
```

(replace *3* with your number of choice).